# ¿Como obtener array desde servicio angular de dos collecciones firestore?

Tags: angular

Buen dia tengo esta funcion en un servicio angular, la cual hice para relacionar dos colecciones en firestore: alumnos y pagos, la idea es recorrer la coleccion alumnos y por CADA UNO de ellos buscar sus pagos y asi ir uniendo ambos en un arreglo para despues consumirlo en un componente al que le paso: datosUsuario y asi llenar facilmente una tabla (no se me ha ocurrido otra mejor manera, acepto todas las sugerencias)

```
async getUsersConMesesPagados(){
  const userRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('users');
  const pagosRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('pagos/2020/pagosResumen');

  let datosUsuario = [];
  let pagosUsuario;

  const users = await userRef.get().then( usuarios => {
    // console.log('data en GetUsers: ', dusuariosata);
    usuarios.forEach( async user => {
      let usuario = user.data();
      let pagos = await pagosRef.doc(user.id).collection('pagos').get();
      pagos.forEach( pagos => {
        // Pagos por usuario console.log('pagos', pagos.data());
        pagosUsuario = pagos.data();
      });

      let datosJuntos = [];
      datosJuntos = {...usuario, ...pagosUsuario};
      datosUsuario.push( datosJuntos ) ;
    });
  });
  // console.log('datos usuarios:', datosUsuario);
  return datosUsuario;
}
```

En el componente lo llamo asi:

```
  verPagos(){
    if (this.form.valid){
     this.pagosPorYear$ = this.adminService.getPagosPorYear(this.yearField, this.statusField, this.grupoField);

     this.adminService.getUsersConMesesPagados()
     .then( data => {
       // si quiero ver lod datos SI me muestra todo el array
      console.log('datos que vienen de funcion', data);
      // si quiero ver por ejemplo la longitud me dice que CERO como si no tuviera nada
      console.log('longitud del array: ', data.length);
      this.alumnosPagos = data;
      console.log('No muestra nada: ', this.alumnosPagos);
     });

    }
  }
```

pero el problema es que si le pido un console.log de los datos si los veo pero como que aun no estan cargados que no puede utilizarlos el data-table, me parece que el problema es ese: Value below was evaluated just now, porque si hago por ejemplo un .lenght de esa variable me dice que es cero :(, no se como hacer esto o que me recomienden hacer para lograr ese objetivo :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que las llamadas asíncronas que haces dentro del `then` no se esperan porque el `await` no funciona con el `forEach`. Puedes usar `for-of` que implementa iteradores y funciona con `async/await`.
Por eso cuando se resuelve el `get` de `users` se devuelve el `datosUsuario` que tiene longitud 0 porque el `await` no funciona con el `forEach`.

Prueba así a ver si te va.
He puesto commentarios en tu código por que hay cosas que me parecen que son incorrectas.

```
async function getUsersConMesesPagados(){
  const userRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('users');
  const pagosRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('pagos/2020/pagosResumen');

  let datosUsuario = [];
  let pagosUsuario;

  const users = await userRef.get();

  for (let user of users.docs) {
    let usuario = user.data();
    let pagos = await pagosRef.doc(user.id).collection('pagos').get();
    pagos.forEach( pagos => {
      // Pagos por usuario console.log('pagos', pagos.data());
      // Esto no se entiende porque estas reasignando los pagos en cada itereción?
      pagosUsuario = pagos.data(); 
    });

    let datosJuntos = []; // esto no debería ser un objeto? se puede simplificar asi
    // let datosJuntos = {...usuario, ...pagosUsuario};
    datosJuntos = {...usuario, ...pagosUsuario};
    datosUsuario.push( datosJuntos ) ;
  }
  // console.log('datos usuarios:', datosUsuario);
  return datosUsuario;
}
```

Comment: intente probar lo que comentas pero en el: for (let user of users) { me aparece el error sobre users: Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488) :( apenas comienzo con Angular ¿me puedes sugerir algo para ese error?

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta. No he usado nunca firestore pero viendo su api creo que debería ser `users.docs` porque la propiedad `docs` es la que tiene el array de documentos.

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho, ahora tengo dudas existenciales para encadenar promesas pero creo que tendré que hacer otra pregunta distinta :)

Comment: pues acepta la respuesta marcando el check a la izquierda. Aqui puedes mirar como encadenar promesas https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: perdona ya acepte la respuesta, nuevamente mil gracias y que en esta pandemia tu y tu familia se encuentren bien.

Comment: Gracias y igualmente. No hay de que para eso esta plataforma.